# Use custom supplied .jar files when building with gradle (not repository)?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a custom build version of a common library that I want my Gradle build to use instead of downloading standard version from any repository.

Ideally, I need to place *jar files of the library in a project's subfolder and make gradle to use that copy of library when building and later running my project.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the docs. You can define a flat directory repository, which is explained [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:flat_dir_resolver):

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib1', 'lib2'
    }
}
```

or you can also include a flat jar file as a dependency, see [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:file_dependencies):

```
dependencies {
    runtime files('libs/a.jar', 'libs/b.jar')
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Comment: Flat Dir repositories should be a last resort as this DOES NOT support dependency meta data (eg transitive dependencies). You should explore composite build and also local directory based maven repository rather than flatDir

Comment: Thanks @LanceJava for the important comment.

Comment: it seems it only works when lib directory is at current directory if it is at parent directory it will fail ''' repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs '../lib'
    }
}